# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE on line 103

Tags: php

please i need help. I'm not perfect on this so I followed a tutorial. and i get a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE" on this line:

```
function updatephto($id,$tmpName,$ext){
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName,"photos/userimages/".$id."."$ext) && mysqli_query("UPDATE `register` SET `photo`='".$ext."' WHERE `id`=".$id));
```

}

but in the tutorial, there was no error. Please help me out

Comment: Sure you are a developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add (.) before $ext in `move_uploaded_file`

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName,"photos/userimages/".$id."."$ext)
```

should:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpName,"photos/userimages/".$id."." . $ext)
```

Comment: thanks frozenFire. answered.

Comment: but i need more help. i get this error also:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING. and here is the line given;

Comment: echo "<img src='photos/userimages/'.$userdata['photo'].'.'.$userdata['photo'].' width='200' height='230'>"

Comment: When you start a (php) string literal with double-quotes it has to end with double-quotes, and if you start it with a single-quotes ...a single quote ends it. You have mixed that up twice.

Comment: thanks volkerK, it helped